# "\xED" followed by "t" on UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, devise

I have a rails application and the time I try to run or compile the assets gives this error:

```
"\ xED" followed by "t" on UTF-8
```

In my

> application.rb

you have this key:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. What does the complete message say?

Comment: Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Devise::Sessions#new
"\xED" followed by "t" on UTF-8

Comment: Someone has tried to create a username with an emoji, and your database does not support this? At a guess.

Comment: But this happens when I try to compile the assets or the login screen.

Comment: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xED" followed by "t" on UTF-8
/directory/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:110:in `encode'

Comment: Try and track down where that sequence occurs. You've got a mangled UTF-8 character in one of your source files.

Comment: There was an .js file in my application with invalid characters. I fixed them and it worked again.